# How to Test defined process in TFS which is not default to any teams?

Tags: tfs-2015

I Have created copy(Scrum Process Backup)of my current process(Scrum Process) being followed in TFS, I have added few fields and rules, before I make copied process(Scrum Process Backup)as default process. I want to test how it is working, Please let me know how to test and where to fine option to test

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use some test environment:

1. Install second TFS, upload your process and use any data.
2. Create a new project collection ([Manage project collections in Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/manage-project-collections?view=azure-devops)).